# Bazel cross platform build fails with "Unable to find a CC toolchain using toolchain resolution."

Tags: bazel, bazel-rules, bazel-cpp, bazel-python

I have a python binary that I build with bazel on Mac. Now, I want to create the binary for linux for deployment.

I am following this instruction.

I added

```
platform(
    name = "linux_x86",
    constraint_values = [
        "@platforms//os:linux",
        "@platforms//cpu:x86_64",
    ],
)
```

And when built with the --platforms flag it fails

```
bazel build --platforms=//parser:linux_x86  //parser:parser_bin
ERROR: /private/var/tmp/_bazel_jp/64463e3d7652188cb285edbcf54b686c/external/bazel_tools/tools/cpp/BUILD:58:19: in cc_toolchain_alias rule @@bazel_tools//tools/cpp:current_cc_toolchain: 
Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "/virtual_builtins_bzl/common/cc/cc_toolchain_alias.bzl", line 26, column 48, in _impl
    File "/virtual_builtins_bzl/common/cc/cc_helper.bzl", line 219, column 17, in _find_cpp_toolchain
Error in fail: Unable to find a CC toolchain using toolchain resolution. Target: @@bazel_tools//tools/cpp:current_cc_toolchain, Platform: @@//parser:linux_x86, Exec platform: @@local_config_platform//:host
ERROR: /private/var/tmp/_bazel_jp/64463e3d7652188cb285edbcf54b686c/external/bazel_tools/tools/cpp/BUILD:58:19: Analysis of target '@@bazel_tools//tools/cpp:current_cc_toolchain' failed
ERROR: Analysis of target '//parser:parser_bin' failed; build aborted: Analysis failed
INFO: Elapsed time: 0.127s, Critical Path: 0.00s
INFO: 1 process: 1 internal.
ERROR: Build did NOT complete successfully
```

I have a similar setup for my Go code, that worked without any issue. For the two libraries included, the proto library is included in Go as well, so I assume that is not likely an issue.

Complete bazel code.

```
load("@my_deps//:requirements.bzl", "requirement")

platform(
    name = "linux_x86",
    constraint_values = [
        "@platforms//os:linux",
        "@platforms//cpu:x86_64",
    ],
)

py_library(
    name = "fizz",
    srcs = [
        "BuildAstVisitor.py",
        "FizzLexer.py",
        "FizzParser.py",
        "FizzParserListener.py",
        "FizzParserVisitor.py",
        "PythonLexerBase.py",
        "PythonParserBase.py",
    ],
    visibility = ["//visibility:public"],
    deps = [
        "//proto:ast_py_proto",
        requirement("antlr4-python3-runtime"),
    ],
)

py_binary(
    name = "parser_bin",
    srcs = ["main.py"],
    main = "main.py",
    visibility = ["//visibility:public"],
    deps = [":fizz"],
)
```

If this would help in anyway, when specifying --toolchain_resolution_debug I get

```
bazel build --platforms=//parser:linux_x86  //parser:parser_bin --toolchain_resolution_debug='@bazel_tools//tools/cpp:toolchain_type' 
INFO: ToolchainResolution: Performing resolution of @@bazel_tools//tools/cpp:toolchain_type for target platform //parser:linux_x86
      ToolchainResolution:   Rejected toolchain @@bazel_tools~cc_configure_extension~local_config_cc//:cc-compiler-armeabi-v7a; mismatching values: armv7, android
      ToolchainResolution:   Rejected toolchain @@bazel_tools~cc_configure_extension~local_config_cc//:cc-compiler-darwin_arm64; mismatching values: aarch64, osx
      ToolchainResolution:   Rejected toolchain @@bazel_tools~cc_configure_extension~local_config_cc//:cc-compiler-armeabi-v7a; mismatching values: armv7, android
      ToolchainResolution:   Rejected toolchain @@bazel_tools~cc_configure_extension~local_config_cc//:cc-compiler-darwin_arm64; mismatching values: aarch64, osx
      ToolchainResolution:   Rejected toolchain @@apple_support~~apple_cc_configure_extension~local_config_apple_cc//:cc-compiler-darwin_arm64; mismatching values: osx, aarch64, device
      ToolchainResolution:   Rejected toolchain @@apple_support~~apple_cc_configure_extension~local_config_apple_cc//:cc-compiler-darwin_arm64; mismatching values: osx, aarch64, device
      ToolchainResolution:   Rejected toolchain @@apple_support~~apple_cc_configure_extension~local_config_apple_cc//:cc-compiler-darwin_arm64e; mismatching values: osx, aarch64, device
      ToolchainResolution:   Rejected toolchain @@apple_support~~apple_cc_configure_extension~local_config_apple_cc//:cc-compiler-darwin_arm64e; mismatching values: osx, aarch64, device
      ToolchainResolution:   Rejected toolchain @@apple_support~~apple_cc_configure_extension~local_config_apple_cc//:cc-compiler-darwin_x86_64; mismatching values: osx, device
      ToolchainResolution:   Rejected toolchain @@apple_support~~apple_cc_configure_extension~local_config_apple_cc//:cc-compiler-darwin_x86_64; mismatching values: osx, device
      ToolchainResolution:   Rejected toolchain @@apple_support~~apple_cc_configure_extension~local_config_apple_cc//:cc-compiler-ios_arm64; mismatching values: ios, aarch64, device
      ToolchainResolution:   Rejected toolchain @@apple_support~~apple_cc_configure_extension~local_config_apple_cc//:cc-compiler-ios_arm64; mismatching values: ios, aarch64, device
      ToolchainResolution:   Rejected toolchain @@apple_support~~apple_cc_configure_extension~local_config_apple_cc//:cc-compiler-ios_arm64e; mismatching values: ios, aarch64, device
      ToolchainResolution:   Rejected toolchain @@apple_support~~apple_cc_configure_extension~local_config_apple_cc//:cc-compiler-ios_arm64e; mismatching values: ios, aarch64, device
      ToolchainResolution:   Rejected toolchain @@apple_support~~apple_cc_configure_extension~local_config_apple_cc//:cc-compiler-ios_armv7; mismatching values: ios, armv7, device
      ToolchainResolution:   Rejected toolchain @@apple_support~~apple_cc_configure_extension~local_config_apple_cc//:cc-compiler-ios_armv7; mismatching values: ios, armv7, device
      ToolchainResolution:   Rejected toolchain @@apple_support~~apple_cc_configure_extension~local_config_apple_cc//:cc-compiler-ios_i386; mismatching values: ios, i386, simulator
      ToolchainResolution:   Rejected toolchain @@apple_support~~apple_cc_configure_extension~local_config_apple_cc//:cc-compiler-ios_i386; mismatching values: ios, i386, simulator
      ToolchainResolution:   Rejected toolchain @@apple_support~~apple_cc_configure_extension~local_config_apple_cc//:cc-compiler-ios_sim_arm64; mismatching values: ios, aarch64, simulator
      ToolchainResolution:   Rejected toolchain @@apple_support~~apple_cc_configure_extension~local_config_apple_cc//:cc-compiler-ios_sim_arm64; mismatching values: ios, aarch64, simulator
      ToolchainResolution:   Rejected toolchain @@apple_support~~apple_cc_configure_extension~local_config_apple_cc//:cc-compiler-ios_x86_64; mismatching values: ios, simulator
      ToolchainResolution:   Rejected toolchain @@apple_support~~apple_cc_configure_extension~local_config_apple_cc//:cc-compiler-ios_x86_64; mismatching values: ios, simulator
      ToolchainResolution:   Rejected toolchain @@apple_support~~apple_cc_configure_extension~local_config_apple_cc//:cc-compiler-tvos_arm64; mismatching values: tvos, aarch64, device
      ToolchainResolution:   Rejected toolchain @@apple_support~~apple_cc_configure_extension~local_config_apple_cc//:cc-compiler-tvos_arm64; mismatching values: tvos, aarch64, device
      ToolchainResolution:   Rejected toolchain @@apple_support~~apple_cc_configure_extension~local_config_apple_cc//:cc-compiler-tvos_sim_arm64; mismatching values: tvos, aarch64, simulator
      ToolchainResolution:   Rejected toolchain @@apple_support~~apple_cc_configure_extension~local_config_apple_cc//:cc-compiler-tvos_sim_arm64; mismatching values: tvos, aarch64, simulator
      ToolchainResolution:   Rejected toolchain @@apple_support~~apple_cc_configure_extension~local_config_apple_cc//:cc-compiler-tvos_x86_64; mismatching values: tvos, simulator
      ToolchainResolution:   Rejected toolchain @@apple_support~~apple_cc_configure_extension~local_config_apple_cc//:cc-compiler-tvos_x86_64; mismatching values: tvos, simulator
      ToolchainResolution:   Rejected toolchain @@apple_support~~apple_cc_configure_extension~local_config_apple_cc//:cc-compiler-watchos_arm64; mismatching values: watchos, aarch64, simulator
      ToolchainResolution:   Rejected toolchain @@apple_support~~apple_cc_configure_extension~local_config_apple_cc//:cc-compiler-watchos_arm64; mismatching values: watchos, aarch64, simulator
      ToolchainResolution:   Rejected toolchain @@apple_support~~apple_cc_configure_extension~local_config_apple_cc//:cc-compiler-watchos_arm64_32; mismatching values: watchos, arm64_32, device
      ToolchainResolution:   Rejected toolchain @@apple_support~~apple_cc_configure_extension~local_config_apple_cc//:cc-compiler-watchos_arm64_32; mismatching values: watchos, arm64_32, device
      ToolchainResolution:   Rejected toolchain @@apple_support~~apple_cc_configure_extension~local_config_apple_cc//:cc-compiler-watchos_armv7k; mismatching values: watchos, armv7k, device
      ToolchainResolution:   Rejected toolchain @@apple_support~~apple_cc_configure_extension~local_config_apple_cc//:cc-compiler-watchos_armv7k; mismatching values: watchos, armv7k, device
      ToolchainResolution:   Rejected toolchain @@apple_support~~apple_cc_configure_extension~local_config_apple_cc//:cc-compiler-watchos_i386; mismatching values: watchos, i386, simulator
      ToolchainResolution:   Rejected toolchain @@apple_support~~apple_cc_configure_extension~local_config_apple_cc//:cc-compiler-watchos_i386; mismatching values: watchos, i386, simulator
      ToolchainResolution:   Rejected toolchain @@apple_support~~apple_cc_configure_extension~local_config_apple_cc//:cc-compiler-watchos_x86_64; mismatching values: watchos, simulator
      ToolchainResolution:   Rejected toolchain @@apple_support~~apple_cc_configure_extension~local_config_apple_cc//:cc-compiler-watchos_x86_64; mismatching values: watchos, simulator
      ToolchainResolution:   Rejected toolchain @@local_config_cc//:cc-compiler-armeabi-v7a; mismatching values: armv7, android
      ToolchainResolution:   Rejected toolchain @@local_config_cc//:cc-compiler-darwin_arm64; mismatching values: aarch64, osx
      ToolchainResolution: No @@bazel_tools//tools/cpp:toolchain_type toolchain found for target platform //parser:linux_x86.
INFO: ToolchainResolution: Target platform //parser:linux_x86: Selected execution platform @@local_config_platform//:host, type @@bazel_tools//tools/python:toolchain_type -> toolchain @@bazel_tools//tools/python:_autodetecting_py_runtime_pair
INFO: ToolchainResolution: Target platform //parser:linux_x86: Selected execution platform @@local_config_platform//:host, 
ERROR: /private/var/tmp/_bazel_jp/64463e3d7652188cb285edbcf54b686c/external/bazel_tools/tools/cpp/BUILD:58:19: in cc_toolchain_alias rule @@bazel_tools//tools/cpp:current_cc_toolchain: 
Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "/virtual_builtins_bzl/common/cc/cc_toolchain_alias.bzl", line 26, column 48, in _impl
    File "/virtual_builtins_bzl/common/cc/cc_helper.bzl", line 219, column 17, in _find_cpp_toolchain
Error in fail: Unable to find a CC toolchain using toolchain resolution. Target: @@bazel_tools//tools/cpp:current_cc_toolchain, Platform: @@//parser:linux_x86, Exec platform: @@local_config_platform//:host
ERROR: /private/var/tmp/_bazel_jp/64463e3d7652188cb285edbcf54b686c/external/bazel_tools/tools/cpp/BUILD:58:19: Analysis of target '@@bazel_tools//tools/cpp:current_cc_toolchain' failed
ERROR: Analysis of target '//parser:parser_bin' failed; build aborted: Analysis failed
INFO: Elapsed time: 0.400s, Critical Path: 0.00s
INFO: 1 process: 1 internal.
ERROR: Build did NOT complete successfully
```